# Using Kendo UI mobile with Eclipse as Android Application

Tags: android, kendo-ui

I have a small application made in Visual Studio 2010 having only simple HTML pages in which I used Kendo UI mobile. Now I want to use that application as Android Application. Is there any way to do that? Can I convert that application to Eclipse app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PhoneGap. http://phonegap.com .  PhoneGap helps you to bundle apps built using HTML/JSand CSS so that they can be deployed in multiple mobile platforms like android, iOS, blackberry etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an android project that uses webview to show your HTML page. I suggest you read and follow this page (https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) to be able to achieve what you want.